# trying to use fetch in a chain and getting the data to function using a callback

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have been trying to fetch from two API's using a fetch chain. The fetch works and the data displays correctly using `console.log` inside the `getallproducts` function, but when I try to make a callback towards the `displayproducts` function using the data, the data is nowhere to be seen. I do not know exactly what I am doing wrong or if I'm using the wrong method for this but I have been trying multiple methods of fetch. `promise.all` seemed to be a solution but that didn't work either.

**`showProductsPage` function**

```
function showProductsPage() {
    var page = document.getElementById('products-page');
   
    hideAllPages();
    //getAllProducts();
displayproducts(getAllProducts);
    page.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**`getallproducts` function**

```
function getAllProducts(callback){
    var producten; 
var authors; 
    fetch(window.location.href+"api/products")
                .then(response => response.json())              
                .then(data => { 
                         producten = data.products;
                        console.log(data);   
                        callback(data)                
return fetch(window.location.href+"api/authors")
                }).then(response => response.json())              
                .then(data => { 
                         authors = data.authors;
                    callback(data)
                })
                 
}
```

**display products function**

```
function displayproducts(data) {
    console.log(data.products);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
    
    var card = document.createElement("div");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var name = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var author = document.createElement("p");
    var published = document.createElement("p");
    var price = document.createElement("p");
    var cart = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    document.getElementById("products-page").appendChild(card); 
    //
    card.appendChild(img);
    card.appendChild(name);
    card.appendChild(author);
    card.appendChild(published);
    card.appendChild(price);
    card.appendChild(cart);
    //
    card.setAttribute("class", "book-card");
    img.setAttribute("class", "product-img");
    name.setAttribute("class", "book-title");
    author.setAttribute("class", "author");
    published.setAttribute("class", "published");
    price.setAttribute("class", "price");
    cart.setAttribute("class", "add-to-cart");
    //
    cart.innerHTML = "Add to Cart";
    name.innerHTML = data.products.title;
    price.innerHTML = data.products.price;
};
  //console.log(producten[1].price);
}
```

Comment: Why are you fetching the authors? `displayproducts` doesn't seem to use them. Also, inside your for loop, you need `data.products[i].title` and the like. Also, here's how to grab multiple pieces of data: https://pastebin.com/raw/x51h0fYB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up the call. This:

```
 displayproducts(getAllProducts)
```

Must be:

```
 getAllProducts(displayproducts);
```

Comment: works now....cant believe it was such a simple mistake, been working on this for a couple days, used a lot of methods but was just this. thanks!